# Passing Jenkins Environment variable with spaces to ansible command ran via groovy file

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, ansible, spaces

I am unable to pass a variable with spaces from a Jenkinsfile to an ansible command ran via groovy.

I have tried using quotes (double and single) backspaces and various other combinations to no avail. 
Unfortunately I cannot rename to include - or _.
Running it as a one liner in linux works with the variable exported to the shell with double quotes. 
When passed from Jenkins the first space breaks the code and the second word in the string is treated like a seperate string.

The variable in question in the Jenkins file...

```
env.COMPUTER_NAME = "HELLO WORLD"
```

In the ansible

```
String computer_args ="ansible-playbook deploy.yml -e COMPUTER_NAME=${env.COMPUTER_NAME}"
```

This would result in the error...

```
Kernel \r on an \m

ERROR! the playbook: WORLD could not be found

Connection to XX closed.

script returned exit code 1
```

However, running in a linux shell, it works

```
export COMPUTER_NAME="HELLO WORLD"
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -e COMPUTER_NAME=${env.COMPUTER_NAME}

TASK [computer_name_gather_facts : fail if Computer name was not found] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}
```

Comment: try `String computer_args ="ansible-playbook deploy.yml -e \"COMPUTER_NAME=${env.COMPUTER_NAME}\""`

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this and the same error persists - For some reason ansible seems unable to use the variable as is with the spaces

Comment: @user2920657, Could you please add your groovy script as well using which I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamVaishnav - all that is being invoked by the groovy file at the moment is 
```String computer_args ="ansible-playbook deploy.yml -e COMPUTER_NAME=${env.COMPUTER_NAME}"```

Comment: This is actually a shell command issue and unrelated to ansible, jenkins, or groovy. Your interpolated command would be `ansible-playbook deploy.yml -e COMPUTER_NAME=HELLO WORLD` which would attempt to execute a playbook called `WORLD` as that is the last argument. You need to fix the typo in your command, and then you will be good to go.

Comment: @MattSchuchard The issue is that the variable has got a space in it and cannot be changed. If it was COMPUTER_NAME it'd be fine, but as is "COMPUTER NAME" doesn't work.

I can get it to work when running the ansible-playbook command as a one liner in the shell, and that is with the variable being set to COMPUTER NAME

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, try this one,

```
/* Groovy script to run ansible script*/
COMPUTER_NAME="Hello World"
def computer_args=["/bin/bash", "-c", /ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml -e COMPUTER_NAME="'${COMPUTER_NAME}'"/]
print(computer_args)
def proc = computer_args.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println "Process exit code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
```

**Ansible Playbook**

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Add a line to a file if the file does not exist, without passing regexp
      debug:
        msg: "{{ COMPUTER_NAME }}"
```

**Output**

```
[root@localhost ~]# groovy check.groovy 
[/bin/bash, -c, ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml -e COMPUTER_NAME="'Hello World'"]Process exit code: 0
Std Err: 
Std Out: 
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
Monday 09 September 2019  15:41:36 +0000 (0:00:00.054)       0:00:00.054 ****** 

TASK [Add a line to a file if the file does not exist, without passing regexp] ***
ok: [192.168.5.206] => {
    "msg": "Hello World"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.5.206              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As you can see, the COMPUTER_NAME is successfully passed to the ansible script.

Comment: Thanks for this - I ended up going on a tangent - whilst the above use case did work, it didnt work in my scenario.

I feel I am closer than I was though frustratingly still encountering an error when going through Jenkins.

On the shell the following works fine.

```docker exec "container_name" bash -c 'export COMPUTER_NAME="Hello World; echo $COMPUTER_NAME; ansible-playbook deploy.yml -e "{\"COMPUTER_NAME\":['"$COMPUTER_NAME"']}"'```

But in Jenkins...

```No such DSL method -e "{"COMPUTER_NAME":[' found among steps```

Comment: @user2920657, Now you have brought Docker in the picture it was not present earlier, your use case is a bit cloudy. Please add the complete code which you are using, the environment where you are running and the error you are facing in the question, and I will have a look. As what you are saying now, was not there in your last issue.